# S3FS Node and Express, s3fsImpl is not defined

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fs

I am trying to put a file into a s3 bucket from my node server using a post request in node.js. Here is the part of my node server that sets up the routes.

```
// Get Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Get API Routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const app = express();

// Parse for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// post static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);
```

Here is api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var S3FS = require('s3fs');
var s3fsImp1 = new S3FS('bucketname',{
        accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
});

router.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Connected!' });
});

router.post('/upload',(req,res) => {
  var file = req.body.file;
  console.log(file);
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(file)
  return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file,stream).then(function(){
    fs.unlink(file,function(err){
      if(err)
        console.error(err);
    });
    res.send('done');
  }).catch(function (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({
      message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Node throws the error `ReferenceError: s3fsImpl is not defined` when I call that post method from postman. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you used 1 instead of the letter 'l' in the declaration. That may be the issue.

Comment: That fixed it! I can't believe I overlooked that! Thanks